# og image tag link as protocol independent

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am looking to see, if I can set the og:image tag without specifying the protocol and have it take on the browser protocol or default http protocol.

For example,

```
<meta property="og:image" content="//kbob.github.io/images/sample-2.jpg" />
```

Will it work on all cases and all browsers ? or do we have to force a protocol to the content URL ?

Comment: What makes you think user browsers had anything to do with this? This information is only relevant for the Facebook scraper, that will fetch the image and place a copy on their CDN.

Comment: Good point. Browser is not in picture. Will Facebook scraper use the http or https protocol to fetch the image (given the protocol is not specified) ?